# What are the vectors $v$ and $w$, given the permutation matrices....

Tags: matrices

I want to determine the vectors $v$ and $w$, given the following product:
\begin{align*}
P_x &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\ P_y = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},\\
P_x v &= -\frac v2 + \frac{\sqrt{3}w}{2},\\
P_x w &= -\frac v2 - \frac{\sqrt{3}w}{2},\\
P_y v &= v,\\
P_y w &= -w,
\end{align*}
where $v$ and $w$ are nonzero vectors.

For this problem, I let $v$ and $w$ be arbitrary nonzero vectors and then, worked out the computation by substitution and taking product of matrices.  However, I get zero vectors as the results.

Any advices or comments?

Comment: Have you figured out the eigenspaces of $P_y$?

Comment: You are correct. There are no nontrivial solutions. $v$ and $w$ must be zero.

Comment: Should the second equation be $P_x w=\dfrac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}v-\dfrac12w$?

Comment: Ah hah!  There are zero vectors, so I need to switch either of the equation with a half and $\sqrt{3}$'s around.

Comment: @Daryl Then, there will be infinite number of solutions.  Actually, yes there will be nonzero solutions.

Comment: @NasuSama To get non-zero solutions there will be an infinite number of solutions. You are essentially solving a homogeneous linear system of size $12\times6$. The only way to get non-zero solutions is for an infinite number of them.